# Display X items at a time with ListView.builder

Tags: listview, flutter

I have a list made up of object like this:

```
Object Name + Icon + Icon
Line
```

([ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mNF7x.png)).

And to show them I use a ListView.builder() widget

I was wondering if I could make the ListView.builder display 5 or so items at a time and when the user scrolls down snap instead of smoothly running until the list ends. (Like a `PageView.builder` with `pageSnapping` on). 
And the height of the ListView widget should be equal to for example 5 time the height of a child.

I found nothing online, so is there a way I could do it?

Comment: add your code  please

Comment: the code for the items?